# How to give write permission to specific user in a read only directory?

Tags: linux, permissions, freenas

System: FreeNAS

There is a directory:

```
drwxr-xr-x  4 user1  Group1    7 Mar 14 01:48 publicDirectory
```

User `user1` gets to upload files here, and all the users within the `Group1` get `-xr` rules, and that's great.

But there are a handful of users, let's say, `user4` and `user15` (let's call them, "directory maintainers"), that need to have `wxr` rights, but nobody else.

How would I go about doing that? I am still a beginner.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You're off by one – the permissions are grouped into `rwx`/`r-x`/`r-x`, not `wxr`.

```
d rwx r-x r-x  4 user1  Group1    7 Mar 14 01:48 publicDirectory
```

In your case, since "Others" or "World" has exactly the same `r-x` permissions as the group does, it should be fine to just switch the group ownership to a different group and give it the write permission – for example:

```
d rwx rwx r-x  4 user1  Maintainers    7 Mar 14 01:48 publicDirectory
```

If you want more complex configurations (e.g. Maintainers rwx, Group1 rx, everybody else no access), that can be done using ACLs which allow you to add multiple users and/or groups. It seems that FreeNAS is configured to use "NFSv4" ACLs (which are similar to those on Windows) rather than "POSIX" ACLs; [see documentation](https://www.ixsystems.com/documentation/freenas/11.3-RELEASE/storage.html#acl-management).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! yeah, I messed up the order, it should be `r-x`.
However, I cannot switch the group permissions. One of the requirements for RSYNC (which, user1 is using to upload stuff), has to have no group write permissions. "Others" permissions don't even matter to me.

Unless somebody could educate me how to get around rsync over ssh group no write permissions, I think I would need to use ACLs, BUT FreeNAS is not happy with allowing SSH access if the pool is using ACLs... it's all very constraining and I am confused as to why :(